# push rails app to heroku fails in bundle supports no platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundle, bundler

when I push my rails-app to heroku it fails at the bundling step because it doesn't match the platform. I tried to change or remove the ruby tag from Gemfile but it doesn't change anything. It fails because my bundle does not support any platform [] (guess should be ruby in there).

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17/17), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.96 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.7
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your bundle only supports platforms [] but your local platforms are ["ruby",
remote:        "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists.
remote:        Bundler Output: Your bundle only supports platforms [] but your local platforms are ["ruby",
remote:        "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to evening-brushlands-95986.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-brushlands-95986.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-brushlands-95986.git'
```

On my local machine it satisfies the platform

```
bundle platform
Your platform is: x86_64-linux

Your app has gems that work on these platforms:
* ruby

Your Gemfile specifies a Ruby version requirement:
* ruby 2.5.0p0

Your current platform satisfies the Ruby version requirement.
```

Even if I specify a ruby 2.5 in my Gemfile, heroku uses ruby-2.3.7

my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  # gem 'byebug', platforms: [:ruby, :mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'administrate', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'data-confirm-modal', '~> 1.6.2'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4.3'
gem 'devise-bootstrapped', github: 'excid3/devise-bootstrapped', branch: 'bootstrap4'
gem 'devise_masquerade', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', github: 'mdeering/gravatar_image_tag'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.4'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.0'
gem 'foreman', '~> 0.84.0'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '~> 1.4'
gem 'omniauth-github', '~> 1.3'
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'sitemap_generator', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
```

anyone had this before?

regards Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@toy I think some of the gem dependencies problems. Either you can remove the Gemfile.lock and do `bundle install` then commit and push or do  `bundle update` then commit and push along with the Gemfile.lock

```
1) Remove Gemfile.lock
2) bundle install
3) git add Gemfile.lock
4) git commit -m 'Gemfile.lock added'
5) git push heroku master
```

OR

```
1) bundle update
2) git add Gemfile.lock
3) git commit -m 'Gemfile.lock added'
4) git push heroku master
```

Comment: I tried both, without success. So I reduced my Gemfile to only include two lines (source 'https://rubygems.org' and gem 'rails')  did a bundle install, but even than I get the same error

Comment: thanks "bundle update" does the trick, I was just pushing my master branch while working on another.